# What are the alternatives of "based on that" in academic writing?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, academic-writing

I have the following statement:

> The algorithm A produces more equal fitness values than algorithm B.
> Based on that, one possible explanation of why the search peroformance
> with algorithm A is not as efficient as with algorithm B is that ....

I have used Based on that so many times in my thesis, so I wonder if there are better alternatives that I  can use.

Can you suggest some alternatives please?

Comment: Simply start with "One possible explanation of why." Trust your reader to see that what you write has a flow of logic. Based on that idea, you need no fluff to introduce your next sentence. Or ... You need no fluff to introduce your next sentence.

Comment: *Given that*, *because of that*, *therefore*, *hence*, *as such*, *for this reason*, *accordingly*, *consequently*, and any number of other synonyms.

Comment: *Accordingly* is another. You could just begin the sentence with "One possible explanation of why ..."  You should also modify your peroformance or find a problem in your performance.

Comment: Don't you think you'd find more suitable help at SE Writing?